# Como soluciono este error en Access y vb

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

Necesito ayuda con el siguiente error en las siguientes imágenes se muestra el código en el cual se da el error

[image: imagen de un error]

Comment: ayudaria si pones el codigo como texto en lugar de una imagen

Comment: Coloca el código dentro de la pregunta y muestra tambien el error que te arroja el código. Será de gran ayuda

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedo comentar es que deberias usar parametros, concatenar los valores del DELETE en el string no es una buena practica

```
Dim eliminar As String = "DELETE FROM cuarto WHERE id = @Id"
Dim c As New oleDbCommand(eliminar, conexion)
c.parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Convert.Toint32(textid.Text))
c.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Ademas es importante asignar el parametro respetando el tipo de datos, si el campo id es numerico debes asignar el parametro con un numero valido

Nota: si el id es nuemrico el quita las comillas simples